# Dropbox icon missing in the xubuntu plugin area

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dropbox

The dropbox icon from the desktop plugin area is missing and in its place there is a black TV [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFTLX.png) with a red sign in its center. I tried to solve this issue by removing and reinstalling dropbox and by following the proposed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358913/no-dropbox-icon-in-the-indicator-panel). Neither one solution nor the other solved my problem.

Someone can help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Black TV instead of dropbox icon]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some workarounds until the bug is fixed. The best one at this moment (working for Linux distros such as Xubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.) is:

```
dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
```

More details at another StackExchange site: [Dropbox icon is not working Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/736205/506976)

**Update:**

And a [more recent workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/739018/506976) that works for more Linux operating systems:

```
dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.  I noticed that my .dbus directory was owned by root:root with a permission on 700.  Changed ownership recursively to user:user and ran the more recent workaround and it seems to work.